# C# caching a txt file or using File.ReadLines

Tags: c#, performance, caching

I am using File.ReadLines() on the same few files often and don't know the overhead associated with reading a file in this way?

I am searching for each file id (hash) within a txt file.

At the moment I am using this code but wonder if I should cache these index files. My hesitation is that the files will be edited so often that it will cause just as much performance hit by reloading the file in to cache each time. It is much more likely that I will be adding a line to the text file on each iteration (there will not be a match).

```
foreach (var myfile in allfiles) // roughly 5 thousand
{
...

    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(myfile.path + "\index.txt"))
    {
        // compare the line to the current record's hash
        if (myfile.hash.equals(line))
            ...
            return x;

    }
...
// otherwise add a new line (a hash) to index.txt
}

...
```

There are about 5-10 index.txt files at different paths that need to be checked depending on the file... so each one would need to be cached.

Is caching the index.txt file a better idea? Does File.ReadLines() have a lot of overhead?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: I think you'll have to test this one yourself as there isn't an easy or accurate way for anyone to answer this. My gut says that using a `Dictionary` for this would be faster, but you won't know until you test it. Build it and test it.

Comment: The question is can you store all the files in ram anyways? I mean these are 5k files, right?

Comment: When it comes to performance, don't work on assumptions. Measure the execution times with a profiler, and from there you'll know for sure whether the overhead is acceptable or not

Comment: If you don't know then clearly you don't have a problem.  Don't fix imaginary problems.

Comment: @HansPassant this is very important for C# - as long as you don't have a problem with performance, ignore the optimizing aspect

Comment: If you gonna try caching put those hashes from single index.txt file into HashSet or Dictionary to avoid line-by-line comparison. Then, if match cannot be found, add hash to corresponding hashset and append hash line to corresponding index.txt. Then again, if more than one instance of your application run simultaneously, or some other agent writes to files at the same time, you will need more robust solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have *many* files that are *short enough*, *caching* looks reasonable:

```
  // Simplest, not thread safe
  private static Dictionary<String, String[]> s_Files = 
    new Dictionary<string, string[]>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

  private static IEnumerable<String> ReadLines(String path) {
    String[] lines;

    if (s_Files.TryGetValue(path, out lines))
      return lines;
    else {
      lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

      s_Files.Add(path, lines);

      return lines;   
    }
  }

  ...

  foreach (var myfile in allfiles) {
    ...
    // Note "ReadLines" insread of "File.ReadLines"
    foreach (var line in ReadLines(myfile.path + "\index.txt")) {
    }
  }
```

Compare both implementations - your current one - and - this cached routine and then decide whether or not you'd want to cache.

Comment: This is great, thanks.  However in my example, if there is no match then a new line is added to the index.txt file. This means it would need to be reloaded in to the cache. This would happen often.

Comment: I have ended up using a slightly modified version of this (using the dictionary to store file contents). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following:

1. store in memory the last updated timestamp for each hash file
2. cache the content of hash files
3. upon access to cache check if last updated timestamp of the file is greater than one stored in your memory.
4. use ConcurrentDictionary instead of Dictionary.